# Connection to neo4j using one of the sigma.js function

Tags: neo4j, sigma.js

I am trying to connect sigma.js and neo4j. For connection I want to use this code:

```
sigma.neo4j.cypher_parse = function(result) {
        var graph = { nodes: [], edges: [] },
            nodesMap = {},
            edgesMap = {},
            key; ...
```

But I don't know what exactly mean the variable result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trying the internal function of cypher plugin, it's cool.

Take a look at the JSdoc of the method :

```
/**
 * This function parse a neo4j cypher query result, and transform it into
 * a sigma graph object.
 *
 * @param  {object}     result      The server response of a cypher query.
 *
 * @return A graph object
 */
```

So result is the result of the neo4j server. You can take a look at neo4j transaction endpoint : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request

So result is a json object like this one :

```
{
  "results" : [ {
    "columns" : [ "id(n)" ],
    "data" : [ {
      "row" : [ 15 ]
    } ]
  } ],
  "errors" : [ ]
}
```

But why you don't want to use the plugin with its main function like this :

```
mySigmaInstance = new sigma({
  graph: {
      nodes: [],
      edges: []
    },
  container: 'graph-container'
});
sigma.parsers.cypher(
  { url: 'http://localhost:7474', user:'neo4j', password:'admin' },
  'MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) RETURN n,r,m LIMIT 100',
  mySigmaInstance,
  function() {
    // Put here your custom code
    // It's the callback function
    mySigmaInstance.refresh();
  }
);
```